# AttributeError: module 'typing' has no attribute '_SpecialForm'

Tags: python, discord

I'm trying to create a Discord bot but every time I run the code, it says AttributeError: module 'typing' has no attribute '_SpecialForm' even if the code is just "import discord".

Comment: Which version of Python are you on? [_"Python 3.5.3 or higher is required"_](https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/#installing).

Comment: It is probably because one of the dependencies discord has is using incompatible versions with your version of python. You might want to try installing a different version of [typing_extensions](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/).

Answer (score -1):

Run this below command. This rectified my issue.

```
pip install typing-extensions==3.10.0.2
```